# Best SQL Option for Performance

Tags: java, sql, mysql

I currently need to execute a database query that involves data from three separate tables.
(**bases,member,sell_transaction**)

The **bases** table looks like the following
**base_id(PK)    name    state**

The **member** table looks like the following
**id(PK)    last_name    username   email    first_name**

The **sell_transaction** table has the following schema
**transaction_id(PK)    city    
state    
base_id    
date    id   
agentId**

**NOTE- these tables contain more columns, but they are irrelevant, so I am going to save the time and not write them out.**

I am working on a transaction inquiry that involves data from all of these tables. I need to return this data in a TransactionItem that I am populating from these three tables

The TransactionItem as a Pojo looks like the following

```
public TransactionItem(){

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String baseName;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private Date date;

    public String getFirstName(){
              return firstName;
    }
    public String setFirstName(String firstName){
              this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    ...
    ...///The rest of the getters and setters
    ...
    ...


}
```

Currently I am doing three separate selects from each table, which is taking longer then I would like. I would image that there is a way I could use a join or nested select statements,etc.

The data and conditions and their corresponding tables are as follows

I need...
**first_name, last_name,id** from **member**

I need
**name** and **state** from **bases** where **base_id** from **sell_transaction** is equal to **base_id** from  **bases**

Again there is more that I need, but it is redundant to name them off, The idea should still be clear, I need to query data that is dependent on each other. I am not sure performance wise what is the best performance option. The amount of data that is being traversed could end up being very large or very small(not sure if that matters).

select       
    b.name,b.state,
    s.city,s.state,s.duty,s.branch,s.date,
    m.first_name,m.last_name,m.email,m.phone,m.id,s.transaction_id
from 
    bases as b, sell_transaction as s, member as m
where 
    s.agentId is null  and 
    s.username = m.username and 
    b.base_id = s.duty

Comment: Why do you have state in more than one table? Are they the same data? If so, which table should be the canonical source?

Comment: is the relation of AgentID the foreign key to your Member table?

Comment: they are not the same data, they have different meanings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select first_name, last_name, member.id member_id, bases.name, bases.state
from bases, sell_transaction, member
where sell_transaction.base_id = bases.base_id
and member.id = sell_transaction.agentId;
```

I am going out on a limb here and *guessing* that `agentID` is the connection to `member` from `sell_transaction`, but it's not clear or obvious, and possibly incorrect (unless you clarify your data model).

Comment: agentId is not the connection to member, in fact I did not list it, but the sell_transaction table also has an id column that is referencing the id column in member

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum: If you omit important columns it will be hard for us to help. You had two "I need..." statements but it was not clear if you wanted two separate result sets or one. I assumed one because that's what is usually wanted, and it sounded like you only wanted one query. Maybe you could give a sample of the expected results, and the queries you currently use.

Comment: I apologize, I did not purposefully omit the important columns, I am really looking for advice on what would be a better option, I can do nested select statements, I can do something similar to the statement above, or I can do a triple join type statement. Of the three, is there one that would be noticeably better then the other.

Comment: CitadelCSAlum: Again, it's hard to know which strategy will work best for you without knowing more about your system. Try writing all three queries and run them through a query analyser to see which performs best. If you have indexed any of these columns, that will also have an impact on performance.

Comment: I have edited the above with the query that I have been using, hopefully it will give you a better idea of what I am using.

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum: Yes, that does give me a much clearer idea of what you're doing. Unless you've experienced actual performance problems with this query, leave it alone. If you *do* have performance problems, use a query analyser on it, and then maybe index some of these tables. I would suggest an index on `sell_transaction.user_name` and `sell_transaction.duty` (hard to say if they should be a combined index or not), and `member.username`; I assume that `bases.base_id` is already indexed... These suggestions are only based on this query you gave.